# Issue in mapping response to create dynamic table

Tags: jquery

I want to implement a table using jQuery. Below is the sample response which I need to map.

```
[{"type":"Function/Class/Object","count":5,"details":[{"issueId":"otfa_10_R5.9_23","buildId":"otfa_10_R5.9","description":"Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 16 to the 15 allowed.","date":"2019-08-19","drmtype":"Function/Class/Object","recommendation":"Create a way to map requirements and its variations  to coded functions"},{"issueId":"otfa_10_R5.9_42","buildId":"otfa_10_R5.9","description":"Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 17 to the 15 allowed.","date":"2019-08-19","drmtype":"Function/Class/Object","recommendation":"Create a way to map requirements and its variations  to coded functions"}]},{"type":"Algorithm/Method","count":1,"details":[{"issueId":"otfa_10_R5.9_50","buildId":"otfa_10_R5.9","description":"13 duplicated blocks of code must be removed.","date":"2019-08-19","drmtype":"Algorithm/Method","recommendation":"Ensure formulas are validated / proven"}]}]
```

I want to show `type` in first column, `count` in second column, and fixed text `Details` in the third column. Hovering on `Details`, i want to show `description` and corresponding `recommendation`.

But there is some issue with mapping the data itself.

HTML Code:

```
<tr id="reportTableTR">
                                                    <th>Issue Type</th>
                                                    <th>Count</th>
                                                    <th></th>
                                                </tr>
```

JS Code:

```
$.each(data, function(key,value) {
                        table.append('<tr id=reportTableData><td>'+value.type+'</td>'+'<td>'+value.count+'</td>'+'<td>'+ "Details" + '</td></tr>');
                });
```

-> data contains the response.

What I am missing in the first part? The hover thing can be implemented after that only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simply that you are using `append()` on a table row, so you're nesting a row inside another row.

Assuming that you have a proper table structure around your rows (i.e., at minimum a `<table>` tag with a `<tbody>` tag inside it), the easiest thing to do would be to simply move the `reportTableTR` ID up onto the `<tbody>`.

```js
const data = [{"type":"Function/Class/Object","count":5,"details":[{"issueId":"otfa_10_R5.9_23","buildId":"otfa_10_R5.9","description":"Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 16 to the 15 allowed.","date":"2019-08-19","drmtype":"Function/Class/Object","recommendation":"Create a way to map requirements and its variations  to coded functions"},{"issueId":"otfa_10_R5.9_42","buildId":"otfa_10_R5.9","description":"Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 17 to the 15 allowed.","date":"2019-08-19","drmtype":"Function/Class/Object","recommendation":"Create a way to map requirements and its variations  to coded functions"}]},{"type":"Algorithm/Method","count":1,"details":[{"issueId":"otfa_10_R5.9_50","buildId":"otfa_10_R5.9","description":"13 duplicated blocks of code must be removed.","date":"2019-08-19","drmtype":"Algorithm/Method","recommendation":"Ensure formulas are validated / proven"}]}];

const table = $('#reportTableTR');

$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  table.append('<tr class="table-row"><td>' + value.type + '</td>' + '<td>' + value.count + '</td>' + '<td>' + "Details" + '</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="reportTableTR">
    <tr>
      <th>Issue Type</th>
      <th>Count</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that I've removed the ID from the table rows you're appending here because IDs should be unique. I made it a class instead. If you want each row to have a unique identifier, you can modify your function to create dynamic IDs on the fly using the `key` param of your function.

---

Alternatively, you can use jQuery's `after()` function if you particularly want to select the first row to start. Here's an example of that, along with adding dynamic IDs to the rows:

```js
const data = [{"type":"Function/Class/Object","count":5,"details":[{"issueId":"otfa_10_R5.9_23","buildId":"otfa_10_R5.9","description":"Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 16 to the 15 allowed.","date":"2019-08-19","drmtype":"Function/Class/Object","recommendation":"Create a way to map requirements and its variations  to coded functions"},{"issueId":"otfa_10_R5.9_42","buildId":"otfa_10_R5.9","description":"Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 17 to the 15 allowed.","date":"2019-08-19","drmtype":"Function/Class/Object","recommendation":"Create a way to map requirements and its variations  to coded functions"}]},{"type":"Algorithm/Method","count":1,"details":[{"issueId":"otfa_10_R5.9_50","buildId":"otfa_10_R5.9","description":"13 duplicated blocks of code must be removed.","date":"2019-08-19","drmtype":"Algorithm/Method","recommendation":"Ensure formulas are validated / proven"}]}];

const table = $('#myTable');

$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  const lastRow = $(table).find('tr:last-child');
  lastRow.after('<tr id="reportTableTR-' + key + '"><td>' + value.type + '</td>' + '<td>' + value.count + '</td>' + '<td>' + "Details" + '</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="reportTableTR">
      <th>Issue Type</th>
      <th>Count</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```